# Syncthing Usage Report - Data syncing?

Tags: syncthing

I have configured **synching usage repor**t locally and I am able to access web UI locally. Now I need to sync my syncing data to usage report database. 1-Is there any way to auto sync syncthing data to usage report database? 2-If no, then How i can fill report table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can set the reporting URL in the Syncthing config, and it’ll report in every 12 hours or thereabout.

Reference available here https://forum.syncthing.net/t/syncthing-usage-report-data-syncing/11202/2